# ipvlan L3 docker can't ping host

Tags: docker

I was playing with ipvlan_mode=l3 by following the tutorial on docker github repo

https://gist.github.com/nerdalert/28168b016112b7c13040#ipvlan-l3-mode-example-usage

After running the commands my host and docker are not able to ping each other.

However two containers on diffrent subnets using the same parent iface are able to ping.

Commands :

```
docker network  create  -d ipvlan \
--subnet=192.168.214.0/24 \
--subnet=10.1.214.0/24 \
 -o ipvlan_mode=l3 ipnet210

# Test 192.168.214.0/24 connectivity
$ docker run --net=ipnet210 --ip=192.168.214.10 -itd alpine /bin/sh
$ docker run --net=ipnet210 --ip=10.1.214.10 -itd alpine /bin/sh

# Test L3 connectivity from 10.1.214.0/24 to 192.168.212.0/24
$ docker run --net=ipnet210 --ip=192.168.214.9 -it --rm alpine ping -c 2 10.1.214.10

# Test L3 connectivity from 192.168.212.0/24 to 10.1.214.0/24
$ docker run --net=ipnet210 --ip=10.1.214.9 -it --rm alpine ping -c 2 192.168.214.10
```

Is there anything I'm missing ?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a static route on the host or upstream router to get a connection between host and docker subnet as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/ipvlan/#ipvlan-l3-mode-example), end of the chapter:

> In order to ping the containers from a remote Docker host or the container
> be able to ping a remote host, the remote host or the physical network in
> between need to have a route pointing to the host IP address of the
> container’s Docker host eth interface.

For example (referenced to the picture) you have to create a route which point all traffic to subnet 172.16.20.0/24 to gateway 192.168.50.10/24.

Answer (score -1):

I found this Q after reading about `ipvlan l3` driver here

- https://docs.docker.com/network/ipvlan/#ipvlan-l3-mode-example

And I see the same behavior on ubuntu 18.04 and ubuntu 20.04, both with:

- kernel `5.4.0-96-generic`
- docker-ce `20.10.12`

I assume it's by design like this that host can't even see those new networks with `ip r`

I would be very interested to hear how external connectivity for containers should work, in docs (link above) it's not explained, just simple picture without any details...not helpful at all.